# how to remove trailing html break from string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string below and I want to remove the trailing 
 but I'm struggling.  Any help?

```
This is a string<br>    
next line<br>
```

So after my function, the string should be

```
This is a string<br>
next line
```

Doing this code below doesn't seem to be working.  Well, it works but it doesn't clear out two trailing breaks.

```
mystring=mystring.replace(/<br>$/,'');
```

So if my string is actually:

```
This is a string<br>
next line<br>
<br>
```

then the code above just returns

```
This is a string<br>
next line
<br>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to remove all trailing `<br>`s, then use a quantifier:

```
/(<br>\s*)+$/
```

`\s` matches any white space characters, so even if there is line break between continuous `<br>`s, it will still match.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzxBc/1/)

Comment: `/(<br\s*\/?\s*>\s*)+$/` This handles more cases like <br/>, <br />, <br / >

Answer (score 1):

If it's the contents of an HTML element, you can just use jQuery to remove the element:

```
$('#container').children('br').last().remove();
```

If it's a string, you can do something like this (still leveraging jQuery):

```
var cleaner = $('<div />').html(mystring);
cleaner.children('br:last-child').remove();
mystring = cleaner.html();
```

I prefer this over splitting on a string or your current RegEx because you're not handling the scenario of a BR tag like this: `<br />`.

### http://jsfiddle.net/TTg3p/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mystring.split('<br>').slice(0,-1).join('<br>');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xg7kG/2/)
:)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, and it seems to work. I  pasted the following into a file and then viewed in firefox, and clicked view source. The second br was not visible in the source.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var mystring = 'This is a string<br>\n next line<br>'
mystring=mystring.replace(/<br>$/,''); 
document.write(mystring);
</script>
</html>
```

Perhaps your mystring variable has an actual linebreak (\n) at the end of it after the br, so your regular expression is not matching?

Comment: Yup.  I just realized it's working.  But my issue is with multiple trailing breaks.  Doh.

Comment: @Mike: So you want to remove all trailing `<br>`s? Then use a quantifier: `/(<br>\s*)+$/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the last trailing `<br>` inside an element, you can use this:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('element')
console.log('Before:', element.innerHTML)

const last = element.childNodes[element.childNodes.length - 1]
if (last.tagName === 'BR') last.remove()
console.log('After:', element.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="element">Some text<br>other text<br></div>
```