# How to remove the br tag from the end of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the string `hello, dude <br> how <br> are <br> you <br>`

How can I remove the `<br>` tag at the end if it exists?

Comment: $("br:last").remove(); would work I think.

Comment: You need to provide us with that you have tried.

Comment: you want to remove the last br tag or all br tag?

Comment: What is your expected output???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove trailing html break from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056106/how-to-remove-trailing-html-break-from-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `substring` function.

```
var str = "how <br> are <br> you <br>";
alert(str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("<br>"))); // check before if <br> is there in the end.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = 'hello, dude how < br> are < br> you < br>';
text = text.replace(/< br>$/, '');
```

Pure javascript.

Advice: Use jquery.

Comment: While I love jQuery, why is your advice to incorporate a whole library for a menial task?  Even your example doesn't use it.

Comment: Yes it is. It would make this whole thing a lot simpler.

Comment: How does jQuery simplify a basic regex?

Comment: good, but it doesn't account for if there is an ending slash, like <br/>
though honestly I would not recommend using br so much. You'd be better off using semantic HTML.

Comment: This works better for me: text.replace(/(<br>\s*)+$/,'') - taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056106/how-to-remove-trailing-html-break-from-string

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var str = "how <br> are <br> you <br>";
var s = str.split("<br>");
if (s[s.length - 1].length == 0) {
    s.pop();
    console.log(s.join("<br>"));
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6469c60g/)

Answer (score 0):

I think if the `<br/>` tag has an side effect on you layout, you can use `CSS` to hide them.

For example:

`br { display: none; }`.

If not, you can try answers above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript alone,

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Or as @Mattigins said, use JQuery like:

[How do I do string replace in JavaScript to convert ‘9.61’ to ‘9:61’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145988/how-do-i-do-string-replace-in-javascript-to-convert-9-61-to-961)

But I think using jquery just for this task is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeEndBr(string) {
var strSplit = string.split("<br>");
while (strSplit[strSplit.length - 1] == "") {
    strSplit.pop();
}

return strSplit.join("<br>");
```

}

This function will return the same string but with no `<br>` in the end. It not only removes the last `<br>`, but it continues to remove it until there is no `<br>` in the end.

Answer (score -1):

this is a function for do that!

jQuery:

```
var text= "how <br> are <br> you <br> my brother";
var items = text.split(" ");

items=f(items,"");
items=items.replace("<br>","");

var items = items.split(" ");

var items=f(items," ");
alert(items);

function f(items,ext){
    var newitem = new Array();
    var j=0;
    for(i=items.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        newitem[j]=items[i]+ext;
        j++;
    }
    items=newitem.join(" ");
    return (items);
}
```

---

### [See Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/417jwyps/2/)